# How can I use this conditional statement within a child (Consumer)

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't get the if (drawing) Draw(onDrawEnd: _onDrawPolygon); statement to pass for some reason. Does anybody know how to do this? Please advise.

```
body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
  SizedBox(
    width:
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, // or use fixed size like 200
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: Consumer<ProviderMaps>(builder: (context, Provmap, widget) {
      return GoogleMap(
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          compassEnabled: true,
          mapToolbarEnabled: true,
          zoomControlsEnabled: true,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          onLongPress: _addMarkerLongPressed,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
          mapType: maptype,
          onTap: (latLng) {
            _selectCenterCircle(latLng);
          },
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            mapController = controller;
            _controller.complete(controller);
            isMapCreated = true;
            changeMapMode();
            subscription.pause();
            changeMapType();
            setState(() {});
          },
          initialCameraPosition:
              CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 10.0),
          circles: _getCircles(),
          markers: _getMarkers(),
          polygons: _getPolygons()
        (() {
        if (drawing) Draw(onDrawEnd: _onDrawPolygon);
      }()));
    }),
  ),

  Column(children: <Widget>[
    if (enableFreeDraw)
      FloatingActionButton(
```

After the above code segment runs the error I'm seeing is,

`NoSuchMethodError _CompactLinkedHashSet<Polygon> has no instance method call..`

I'm guessing it's trying to pull from polygons: _getPolygons(). I don't know how to use the (() { wrapper or if that's even what I should be using.

EDIT:

Sorry for not being clear. I'm pretty new to Dart and I can't wrap my head around why the above does not work. However, this does work:

```
Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                children: <Widget>[
                  GoogleMap(
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: centerCamera,
                      zoom: zoomCamera,
                    ),
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      googleMapController = controller;
                    },
                    onTap: (latLng) {
                      _selectCenterCircle(latLng);
                    },
                    onCameraMove: (position) {
                      centerCamera = position.target;
                      zoomCamera = position.zoom;
                    },
                    circles: _getCircles(),
                    markers: _getMarkers(),
                    polygons: _getPolygons(),
                  ),
//                  if (!drawing) _mapButtons(),
                  if (drawing)
                    Draw(
                      onDrawEnd: _onDrawPolygon,
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

The part I'm trying to get to work in my first set of code is:

if (drawing) Draw(onDrawEnd: _onDrawPolygon);

It works without the consumer statement. Can't get it to work otherwise.

Comment: Your statement right now is gibberish. And we cannot help you, if you don't tell us what you *want to do*.  Please explain in plain English what you want to do and post an [mcve] with the classes and functions you use.

Comment: I want to know how to pass if (drawing) Draw(onDrawEnd: _onDrawPolygon); to my map properly. It works without the consumer but with it, my formatting is thrown off. It will only work properly when passed directly to the GoogleMap, and I don't know how to accomplish that when there's a child: Consumer

Comment: Do you want to pass it to the GoogleMap? To which parameter? What type is `drawing` and what is `Draw`, a widget?

Comment: Yes to the Google Map. I made an edit to show it being passed successfully (without a consumer) drawing is a bool.

Comment: Your `Draw` was in a Stack with `GoogleMaps`. Do you still want it as the second widget in that stack?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you guys. Sorry for being confusing. Adding an answer to my edit now.

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
if (dawing != null)...[
    Draw(onDrawEnd: _onDrawPolygon);
],
```

Comment: Where do you insert that? I can't get it to accept under polygons: _getPolygons()

Comment: Given that you don't know what type `drawing` is or probably even what `Draw` is or if there is a collection to add to... please don't provide wild guesses. Ask for clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want.

If you display `Draw` when `drawing != null` you must write `polygons: _getPolygons(), if (dawing != null)...[
    Draw(onDrawEnd: _onDrawPolygon);
],`

if you write function after `_getPolygons()` you should write for example:
`() => setState(() {
                                _searchBar = true;
                              }),`

Comment: I still think you should write:
`if (dawing != null)...[
    Draw(onDrawEnd: _onDrawPolygon);
],`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion. This works:

```
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width:
                MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, // or use fixed size like 200
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Consumer<ProviderMaps>(builder: (context, Provmap, widget) {
              return GoogleMap(

                myLocationEnabled: true,
                compassEnabled: true,
                mapToolbarEnabled: true,
                zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                onLongPress: _addMarkerLongPressed,
                myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                mapType: maptype,
                onTap: (latLng) {
                  _selectCenterCircle(latLng);
                },
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  mapController = controller;
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                  isMapCreated = true;
                  changeMapMode();
                  subscription.pause();
                  changeMapType();
                  setState(() {});
                },
                initialCameraPosition:
                    CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 10.0),
                circles: _getCircles(),
                markers: _getMarkers(),
                polygons: _getPolygons(),
              );
            }),
          ),
          if (drawing)
            Draw(
              onDrawEnd: _onDrawPolygon,
            ),
```

There was no need for conditional rendering.